# hijacking fedora or ubuntu or windows upgrades on the fly

Tags: firewalls, http-proxy

is It theoretically possible to hijack (I mean substitute on the fly) the fedora or ubuntu or windows packages upgrades if a cracker has owned the company's firewall/proxy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to replace the packages with other files is certainly possible and even quite easy for an attacker who took control of the firewall or proxy. However, these packages are [digitally signed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) with a private key which is owned by the people at the Fedora headquarters, and the attacker will not be able to forge that; his fake packages will be rejected by the Fedora systems which try to use them. This signature uses [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/); see [this page](https://fedoraproject.org/keys) for details.

Of course, such an attacker will still be able to *prevent* upgrades by simply blocking the relevant packages. This alone can be a problem, because it allows him to indefinitely extend the lifetime of known vulnerabilities.

**Edit:** the same applies for just about every other modern OS out there: they all use some sort of signature mechanism on authentic updates. Linux-based OS tend to use the [OpenPGP format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) while Windows relies on derivatives from the X.509 world, e.g. authenticode; but that does not change the concept.

Comment: it's impossible to hijack the pubkey fedora (or ubuntu) repository ?

Comment: It is not _impossible_ but you have to subvert some server which contains the private key. You cannot do that from a machine which is merely between the repository and the system which is to be updated, as your "company firewall/proxy". We do _hope_ that the people who sign the packages protect their machines properly.